# I want to process in two different c# form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, visual-c++

There is a textbox1 in Form1 and a textbox2 in Form2. I am writing a string value in textbox1 and I want to show it in textbox2 in Form2. Form1 is shown on the main screen (pc screen) and Form2 is shown on the second screen (side screen). How can I do this?

Comment: do you want to show the value in `textbox2` after you have typed it in `textbox1` or while you are typing it? are both forms visible at the same time?

Comment: Use a Model and bind both controls to the same data field. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/data-binding-and-windows-forms

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2.textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2.Show();
        }
    }
```

But first you have to change `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2` from `private` to `public` in the `Form2.Designer.cs` file. I assumed here that you are calling `from2` with a `Button` control.